# Code asking if i want to continue even when im not done

Tags: python

Heres the code:

```
else:
        incorrect_guesses.add(guess)
        lives -= 1
        print("Incorrect!")
        if lives == 0:
            print("Sorry, you ran out of lives. The word was:", word)
            break
    play_again = input("Would you like to play again [Y/N]? ").strip().lower()
    if play_again == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
```

keeps asking to play again after every input

Every time I input my answer it asks if i want to try again when i still have lives

```
Welcome to Hangman!
Please choose a size of a word to be guessed [3 - 12, default any size]: 4
Please choose a number of lives [1 - 12, default 6]: 6

Guessed word: _ _ _ _ 
Lives remaining: 6
Please guess a letter or the whole word: T
Correct!
Would you like to play again [Y/N]?
```

is it the placement of items or something else. I am stumped

Comment: Please, check [ask] and post [mre]. Also pay attention to indentation.

Comment: Indent your code properly and you may see the issue.

Comment: the output you posted, it saying you guessed correct answer, it's asking you to play again, and post the complete code , how can someone know what is there in the if block

Answer (score 0):

This is  minimal implementation. The problem in your code was mainly indentation and wrong places where `break` was written.

```py
# Life setup and word setup should be defined in a function called setup() here
while True:
    guess = input("Guess a word: ")
    if guess == word:
        print("Correct!")
        play_again = input("Would you like to play again [Y/N]? ").strip().lower()
        if play_again == 'y': setup() # setup should be a function that you use at the start of the game
        else:
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
    else:
        incorrect_guesses.add(guess)
        lives -= 1
        print("Incorrect!")
        if lives == 0:
            print("Sorry, you ran out of lives. The word was:", word)
            play_again = input("Would you like to play again [Y/N]? ").strip().lower()
            if play_again == 'y': setup()
            else:
                print("Goodbye!")
                break
```